# How to increase the number of permutations in the GLM cross validation function `cv.glm`

Tags: r, glm

I'm wondering if anyone has any experience with specifying a number of permutations in the GLM cross validation function `cv.glm` (package: boot)? I am using the settings `K=2` for splitting my training and validation sets into approximately two equal groups. My `$delta` results can vary widely in some cases depending on the random seed. From the `?cv.glm` help, I cannot see any option for increasing the number of permutations.

#### Example

```
require(boot)

DF <- structure(list(Y = c(0.158507483, 0.008510161, 0.002684648, 0.009587276, 
0.001803681, 0.010173461, 0.002273384, 0.00345826, 0.051424454, 
0.029937484, 0.194813452, 0.042138033, 0.022944148, 0.729585218, 
0.887009621, 0.008899131, 0.001588576, 0.0216036, 0.001409499, 
0.161051383, 0.026504919, 0.001495132, 0.059066545, 0.008317594, 
0.490868633, 0.057027831), X1 = c(0.0974369543591941, -0.11971810600977, 
-0.168908964300336, -0.0011723143713434, -0.200018273737778, 
0.0536459384966756, -0.188248143615029, -0.154736748196712, 0.0529959236206016, 
-0.152396350558232, 0.103766445240172, -0.0693365907826557, -0.114615555500542, 
0.488829422819801, 0.561719898192691, -0.0469180067616361, 0.0631502939411764, 
-0.135689617930714, 0.0343957489602316, -0.0749974069726867, 
-0.107592097416425, 0.067741017650224, -0.167713403634508, 0.275062271178857, 
0.276065626134302, -0.0926000525628916), X2 = c(-0.19192408577628, 
0.116576354094024, 0.208731289320505, -0.138772290234524, 0.364065047213473, 
-0.1574052089755, 0.285540178523006, 0.29343767019163, -0.203222931158516, 
0.0835579872715545, -0.157325117354138, -0.0242157560597033, 
-0.175123479037643, 0.174087353210292, 0.246559485637939, -0.43074835446357, 
-0.0181308378901971, 0.0525230701557242, -0.121813588478372, 
-0.0549274842561502, -0.115591654073407, -0.0190993986035446, 
0.124566313208749, 0.138414677580375, -0.0981459346380045, -0.319191657096572
)), .Names = c("Y", "X1", "X2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-26L))

fmla1 <- formula(Y ~ X1 + X2)
glm1 <- glm(fmla1, DF, family=gaussian(link="log"))
summary(glm1)

set.seed(111)
cv1 <- cv.glm(DF, glm1, K=2)
cv2 <- cv.glm(DF, glm1, K=2)
cv3 <- cv.glm(DF, glm1, K=2)
cv4 <- cv.glm(DF, glm1, K=2)

cv1$delta; cv2$delta; cv3$delta; cv4$delta # RESULTS
#[1] 0.007317702 0.005484949
#[1] 0.12918099 0.06621125
#[1]  1.029601e+31 -3.602880e+16
#[1] 0.02860412 0.01581949
```

Comment: By "permutations", do you mean that you want to run the 2 fold cross-validation multiple times? If so, there is no option in `cv.glm` to do that, but it would be very easy to implement, even with just a loop. However, have you considered using more folds if you want to estimate variability? Have you considered a bootstrap (which seems particularly useful for what you want to do)?

Comment: I didn't realize that you had only 26 points. If this is your real data, then you are going to get very poor convergence on models fit to 13 points.

Comment: @nograpes - Thanks for your efforts here. I think you've got the right approach below. Although this is not the right place to ask this, do you know of any rules of thumb for these `K` settings - i.e. How one chooses between the extremes of 2-fold cross validation vs. "leave-one-out" given the number of samples in the model?

Comment: I don't have a rule of thumb. I think in this case, if you are interested in estimating how much your betas would change due to sampling variability, the variance is the best you are going to get. Since the parameters of glm's have an easily calculable variance, why not just use that? Also, consider throwing in an interaction term, if you plot the data you'll see that you will catch a few outliers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as an example of running the function multiple times, you could do:

```
f<-function() cv.glm(DF,glm1,K=2)$delta
set.seed(111)
replicate(4,f())
#             [,1]       [,2]       [,3]     [,4]
# [1,] 0.013848041 0.05176088 0.06215253 12512004
# [2,] 0.008418343 0.02743163 0.03268880  6256002
```

That gets you a nx2 matrix of results. Just add `n` to taste. (Note that the model will very often not converge with the data you gave. 26 rows isn't enough to split data in two.)